# Why does WordPress convert my jpg's to png?

Tags: images

Anytime I upload an image to the media library it shows up as a png. And when I want to use it in a post WordPress tells me I can't use a png.

How does this happen? The site is in development and running on localhost.

I have changes the .htaccess file to allow bigger files to be uploaded. But after deleting these rules nothing changes. Nothing in functions.php about the media library.

How does this happen? Where should I look to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Probably one of the wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor* files. Are you set up to use ImageMagick or GD to recompress images? I've not heard of either changing JPGs to PNGs though.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE!  The problem you are reporting should be the result of some plugin or custom development. There is nothing in Wordpress Core that would change the file type.  I have also never encountered any preclusion to adding a PNG to a post.  You _definitely_ have  a mystery on your hands. I recommend disabling plugins and/or changing themes until you stop having this problem. It is a major pain, but that should help you identify the source of your problem.

Comment: As @Mike Baxter said, this error is caused by some plugin, So please try disabling the plugins to find the culprit.

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia No it is not there is no plugin being used

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia Problem happens when I converted webp images to jpg and when they are uploaded it get coverted to png

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I tried taking the first sample image from [the Google WebP gallery](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery1), converting it from webp to jpg using ImageMagick and then uploading, and it works fine. How exactly did you convert your images? I tried renaming a .webp to .jpg in case that's what you've done, and you're really uploading a webp file, but WordPress rejected that. I'm using up-to-date WordPress with ImageMagick media handling (check on site health, info)

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: @Rup I used this service to convert https://cloudconvert.com/webp-to-jpg

Comment: Yes that works for me too. (In fact it generates an identical file to ImageMagick, so I guess that's what they're using.)

Answer (score 2):

A peek into the WP core file - **wp-admin/includes/file.php** confirms it is not WP which is doing this. Can you try the following:

1. Check **functions.php** file in your active theme
2. Try switching to other themes and check if the issue persists
3. Try deactivating all the plugins and then activating them one by one and checking the issue
4. Check your **wp-config.php** file
5. Also, can you check whether this plugin is able to convert images from png to jpg or not - https://wordpress.org/plugins/png-to-jpg/

and please reply with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for `Imagick::setImageFormat`, `Imagick` or `setImageFormat` in your theme, if you're using free/bought theme, it would be helpful to mention it as @AndrewL64 mentioned

Answer (score 0):

as OceanG and @Jonas said maybe you are using a plugin or theme that have a function to convert your images. try to search for `Imagick` into your installed and activated plugins and the active theme.

Answer (score 0):

Scenes
I use csv to import products, and the pictures called in the table are all in jpg format.
Images stored locally also have the .jpg suffix. After I dragged the pictures to wordpress, I found that several pictures were automatically converted to png format.
When I was going to use photoshop to save the wrong pictures again in jpg format, I found the problem. Photoshop cannot open those photos. Prompt "Could Not Complete Your Request Because of a Program Error"

The problem is with the picture itself. Try changing the suffixes of the wrong images from .jpg to .png. Throw it into photoshop again, and it can be opened. I am using windows. It should be that the suffixes of these pictures were modified earlier. In windows, after changing the suffix, the file type also changes. But that's just what windows thinks so.

I think I should have described the problem clearly
The solution is to change the erroneous picture back to the .png suffix name, and then use software such as photoshop to save it as .jpg and upload it to wordpress.
windows lied to you

Comment: Oh OK - so you're saying that you actually have PNG format files but saved with a JPG extension? That would probably cause this yes. Where did you get them from that's saving them with the wrong extension?